# Aide in modifying this code removing the ' * ' operator and using while loops instead?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

How can I modify my code and remove the ' * ' operator which I have used to multiply strings and use while loops instead of it to produce the same pattern?

```
i = 1
x = 1
while i <= 4:
    print "v"*x
    print "v"*x
    x = x+1
    i+=1
print "v"*5
b = 4
while b>=1:
    print "v"*b
    print "v"*b
    b=b-1
```

Comment: what's the problem? the newlines?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath      The code works just fine, I only want to use while loops instead of using the star operator (*) while multiplies the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is the simplest way of doing this.

```
length = 4
i = 0
output = "v"
for j in range(length-1):
    print output + "\n" + output
    output += "v"
print output
for j in range(length):
    output = output[:-1]
    print output + "\n" + output
```

Try this out. Hope this helps.

If want to use only while loop..here's the solution.

```
length = 4
i = 1
output = "v"
flag = False
while (i < length):
    if i == 0:
        break
    if not flag:
        print output + "\n" + output
        output += "v"
        i+=1
    else:
        output = output[:-1]
        print output + "\n" + output
        i-=1
    if i == length:
        i-=1
        print output
        flag = True
```

Hope this solves for query. :)

Comment: Yeah that seems a good way of doing it. But I need to use 'while' loops instead of 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using the `range` function and a `for-loop` within your while loop? The `range(stop, end)` function returns an array with integers from `stop` (inclusive) to `end` (exclusive). For ex: `range(0,3)` returns `[0, 1, 2]`. So in a `for-loop`, you could print out `x` number of v's or `b` number of v's by printing a v for each member of the array returned from `range` with each iteration of the outer while loop. For example, it would look like this,

```
i = 1
x = 1
while i <= 4:
    for y in range(0, x):
        print "v"
        print "v"
    x = x+1
    i+=1
print "v"*5
b = 4
while b>=1:
    for y in range(0, b):
        print "v"
        print "v"
    b=b-1
```